# Using string interpolation to change imageView resource in Android studio Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

We can change image by name using string interpolation in Swift. Is there a way to achieve this in Kotlin? Can we change selected image programatically in Kotlin?

```
let image = UIIMage(named : "\(imageName)_selected")
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to get the image using a name computed at runtime, or just in general in your code where you know the ID of the drawable? Typically you'd use `context.resources.getDrawable(R.id.my_drawable_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("${imagename}_selected", "drawable", packageName)
```

Personally, I'd go for a solution like this:

```
val resourceId = when (imageName) {
    "image1" -> R.drawable.image1_selected
    "image2" -> R.drawable.image2_selected
}
```

Although this is a little bit longer, it gives compile time warnings and errors, assuring you the drawable is there.

Perhaps the question is: why are you getting the string imageName? Can it be solved better?